# How to update Mercurial client in CentOS6?

Tags: mercurial, centos

I have Mercurial 1.4 in my CentOS6, but I need to use the Eclipse Plug-in that uses at least Mercurial 1.5. How can I update my Mercurial version in CentOS6?

```
Setting up Install Process
Package mercurial-1.4-3.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

When I try do download a new RPM(mercurial-1.9-1.el6.rfx.x86_64.rpm) and install it, I got this error:

```
emacs-mercurial-1.4-3.el6.x86_64 requires hg = 1.4-3.el6
```

What should I do?

Any clues?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the same purpose I successfully upgraded my hg in CentOS to 2.1.2 by downloading the correct rpm from here:

http://pkgs.repoforge.org/mercurial/

and installing it with yum...

regards

Answer (score 1):

You can install from source, just follow the instructions [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/UnixInstall).

Answer (score 0):

Just run into this while trying to get hg-git working on my CentOS 6 environment.

In 2015 there are RPMs and/or yum repos from the [official download page](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Download).

FWIW - for hg-git I had to pip-install still (package in epel is pretty old and didn't work).